# Header menu included in exported excel sheet in wordpress front pages

Tags: excel, wordpress

```
$now = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT';
  $filename ="analysis_report.xls";
  header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
  header('Expires: ' . $now);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  require(SB_PATH."views/export_analysis/analysis_report_export.php");
  exit;
```

I have to export dynamic html table data in wordpress front users data comes fine but header menu also get included in excel sheet
Same code working fine in wordpress backend.
Here is screenshot
https://prnt.sc/qyw9v6

Please suggest to correct this.

Comment: how are you executing this code?  With a hook, or in a template?

Comment: i using in a hook

Comment: Ok. Which hook? Can you please include the add_action line

Comment: Okay i will add and try basically i create hook of function that called in admin side
and the same functionalities we have to use in forntend on role basis.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague... but the answer to why you are seeing the csv in every file is because you're including it after headers are sent.  This means you need to hook your function into `init` or `admin_init` as the case may be.

Also.. You want to only fire the csv export function when the button is clicked.  What I do is something like this.

```
// CSV Export
if (isset($_REQUEST['do']) && $_REQUEST['do'] == 'download' && $_GET['page'] == 'your-page-slug'){
    add_action('admin_init', 'download_csv_file');
}
```

I fire the csv export with a button on the admin page like this.

```
<a class="button-primary" href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=your-page-slug&do=download');?>&_wpnonce=<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'download_csv' )?>">Download Existing Data</a>
```

I believe with the information above, you should be able to solve your problem.